# web method work fine in iis 6 but not in iis 7 server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7, iis-6

In My Dot net 4.0 web application am using java script to trigger web method. When  my application deployed on IIS 6 Server it works.

But when i deployed it on IIS 7 Server Web Method not working, when i traced it shows this error 500 internal server error.

Please advice

Comment: Is there only one method not working or the whole site?

Comment: Yes only that web method not working, its that dataset converter cant able to add in webconfig file...

Comment: <converters>
            <add name="DataSetConverter" type="Microsoft.Web.Preview.Script.Serialization.Converters.DataSetConverter,Microsoft.Web.Preview" />
            <add name="DataRowConverter" type="Microsoft.Web.Preview.Script.Serialization.Converters.DataRowConverter,Microsoft.Web.Preview" />
            <add name="DataTableConverter" type="Microsoft.Web.Preview.Script.Serialization.Converters.DataTableConverter,Microsoft.Web.Preview" />
          </converters>